# How to eliminate variables "panel1, panel2, panel3 .. etc." in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, optimization, delphi-7

i have this type

```
type
 TMain = class(TForm)

 panel1: Tpanel;
 panel2: Tpanel;
 panel3: Tpanel;
 panel4: Tpanel;
 panel5: Tpanel;
 panel6: Tpanel;
 panel7: Tpanel;
 panel8: Tpanel;
 ......
 panel45: Tpanel;

 label1: TLabel;
 label2: TLabel;
 label3: TLabel;
 label4: TLabel;
 label5: TLabel;
 label6: TLabel;
 label7: TLabel;
 ...........
 label109: TLabel;
```

How can i call this components in one line... inside the Type?

Thank you ...

UpDate....

Base from the anwser i get and accepted  it works great when i have all this components and make the actions like a button1.click from the main form...

But i use to make the actions from units... so

When i click a button i great a procedure DoMaths(Sender: TObject);

```
procedure Tform1.DoMaths(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    if TButton1(Sender).hint := 'Make the standard Package' then
      do_Maths_standard_package;
  end;
```

the do_Maths_standard_package is in unit ComplexMaths.

is the procedure do_Maths_standard_package form unit ComplexMaths it calls some components form Form1... like Form1.label1 etc...

So when i call the RegisterClass(TLabel) and erase the Tlabel from the type it gives an error that it cant find the Label1...

Please can someone help me so not to do the hole program from the start...

Thank you again...

Comment: I suggest you to transform the update part in a new question...

Comment: I make a flag for this Fabricio with comment to moderators if i can do it in a new question or update the existed one no awnser yet... so wait and see...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can delete the name of a TPanel or TLabel then it only exists in the Controls List not in the Type declaration of the form.  You either need to leave one Label and one panel or 
add:

```
initialization
  RegisterClass(TPanel);
  RegisterClass(Tlabel);
end.
```

at the end of the form.

This makes forms with a lot of controls much neater.

Comment: But i have a little problem when i call the panel from a unit it says that he cant find the specific Tpanel that i call... ex. main.great.color := clred it says it cant find the panel great...

Comment: Try adding a (public) procedure to the main form: procedure SetGreat(col: TColor); Then call this.  Does that work?

Comment: Nope my friend... And been more compicate than the start..... Thank you.. But why cant a unit understand the RegisterClass() unit from the main form?

Comment: If one panel on a form has a name you don't need to register the class - Delphi does it automagically.  Same for Labels.  If you need to reference a panel (or Label) programatically you really need to name it (you could iterate through controls but.. why?) That way the number of Panels and labels in the form object declaration is equal to the number that you have to reference at runtime - and they'll have meaningful names not "Label1" won't they :).  The main form is any other form - the .dpr project file is the the REAL main procedure.  You could try Registering a class there but I can'

Answer (score 5):

Use the `TForm.Controls` array:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  Pnl: TPanel;
begin
  for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
    if Controls[i] is TPanel then
    begin
      Pnl := TPanel(Controls[i]);
      Pnl.Caption := 'This is panel ' + IntToStr(i);
    end;
end;
```

Delphi automatically creates two lists for each `TWinControl`:

- `Controls` contains a list of all `TControl` items the control contains.
- `Components` is a list of all the `TComponents` on a control.

Note that all `Controls` are `Components`, but not all `Components` are `Controls`; that's why there are two lists. (A `TDataSet`, for instance, is in the `Components` list, but not in the `Controls` list; a `TEdit`, on the other hand, will be in both.)

You can use the same technique to iterate through the components on a panel or other container as well - `TPanel` has both `Control` and `Component` arrays, for instance.

If what you actually want is to reduce the number of items inside the `type` declaration itself, create them at runtime instead - Delphi will automatically add them to the arrays based on the `Owner` and `Parent`:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  Panel: TPanel;
  Label: TLabel;
begin
  for i := 0 to 10 do
  begin
    Panel := TPanel.Create(Self);  // Set who frees it
    Panel.Parent := Self;   // Set display surface
    Panel.Align := alTop;
    Panel.Name := Format('Panel%d', [i]); // Not necessary
    Panel.Caption := Panel.Name;  

    // Add a label on each panel, just for fun.
    Label := TLabel.Create(Panel); // Panel will free label
    Label.Parent := Panel;         // Label will show on panel
    Label.Top := 10;
    Label.Left := 10;
    Label.Name := Format('Label%d', [i]);
    Label.Caption := Label.Caption;   // Not necessary
  end;
end;
```

Note that creating them yourself is not an "optimization", as it just shifts the loading from the VCL doing it to you doing it yourself. It will reduce the size of the .dfm file, but won't speed up your code or loadtime any, and it means you can't visually lay out the form as well. (It's also much harder to maintain your code, because your controls have meaningless names. It's much easier to know what `LastNameEdit` or `EditLastName` is than `Edit1` when you read the code 6 months from now.)

Comment: "all Components are not Controls" - i bet u meant "not all Components are Controls" instead, or "not every Component is Control" :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The: Thanks. The wording could be improved slightly; fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use arrays:

```
panels : array[1..45] of TPanel;
```

This would allow you to create an array of your controls, and access and use them by index.

Comment: This is wrong. :-) Delphi creates a list of both the `TControls` and `TComponents` on a form automatically, in `TCustomForm.Controls` and `TCustomForm.Components` respectively. (All items dropped on a form are `TComponents`, but not all are `TControls` - the `Components` list includes the `Controls`.) Not downvoting (technically it can be done), but it's not the right way to do it unless you have a need to duplicate the existing arrays for some reason.

Comment: @Ken I'm not sure it's wrong. It's just one part of what you'd do in the create in code part of your answer. Anyway, the question is a bit weak so it's probably worth allowing a little leeway.

Comment: @KenWhite to continue that line - let's get rid of Controls since it only duplicating part of Components. And let's get rid of all those Panel1-like members for they only duplicate correspondent Components[i] value.  The value in Reed's array is exactly that it is array of panels and only of those. Whether that would be useful to certain application is context-depending, but it is not necessary unrtasonable.

Comment: @Arioch'The: Why? We know we're looking for TControls, so using it means we're processing fewer items, and Reed's answer adds the overhead of adding an array of items already contained in two other arrays.

Comment: Because developer may have those very intentions to have list of panels, that to have list of controls. Not always, but why not ? why cannot there be a task that i would want explicilty arry of buttons or array of panels ? you want controls ? iterate components and discard non-controls. Using controls collections is of more comfort and arguably more speed ? same for usint array fo panels when you ONLY need panels.

Comment: @Arioch'The: Speed has nothing to do with it (this whole question deals with "optimization" of something there's entirely no need to optimize, and none of the solutions provide any "optimization"). It's better resource control (not using memory that's not needed), not duplicating code that exists (meaning don't repeat yourself by re-adding what's already there), and not cluttering your code with unnecessary stuff (an extra variable, extra code to assign to the array, etc.) unless there's an absolute need to do so. Some pointess "optimization" effort certainly doesn't need an extra array.

Comment: All those arguments apply to removal of Controls collection and using already existing Components collection instead. BTW, "using memory" and "resource control" is also one kind of optimization. Premature memory economy is a premature optimization too.